# Is there a way to update the input from a sliderInput in a tabsetPanel based on the selected tabPanel in R Shiny?

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

we try to make a Covid-19 simulation based on three different scenarios with R Shiny.
All scenarios got different default values from a sliderInput, that need to be passed to server-functions based on the selected setting and (adittional) user input.

I got the following tabSetPanel in my **UI**:

```
tabsetPanel(id = "inTabset", selected = NULL,
           tabPanel("Großraumbuero",
                    fluidRow(
                      column(4, sliderInput("people",
                                            "Personen im Raum:",
                                            2, 15, 8)) ,
                      
                      column(4, sliderInput("raum",
                                            "Raumgröße (in m²):",
                                            10, 35, 25)),
                      column(4,sliderInput("zeit",
                                           "Aufenthaltsdauer (in Std.):",
                                           1, 16, 8)),
                      
                    )),
           tabPanel("Bar",
                    fluidRow(
                      column(4, sliderInput("people2",
                                            "Personen im Raum:",
                                            2, 15, 15)) ,
                      
                      column(4, sliderInput("raum",
                                            "Raumgröße (in m²):",
                                            10, 35, 23)),
                      column(4,sliderInput("zeit",
                                           "Aufenthaltsdauer (in Std.):",
                                           1, 16, 6)),
                      
                    )),
           tabPanel("Zug",
                    fluidRow(
                      column(4, sliderInput("people3",
                                            "Personen im Raum:",
                                            2, 15, 4)) ,
                      
                      column(4, sliderInput("raum",
                                            "Raumgröße (in m²):",
                                            10, 35, 10)),
                      column(4,sliderInput("zeit",
                                           "Aufenthaltsdauer (in Std.):",
                                           1, 16, 4)),
                      
                    ))
```

And try this in my **R Server:**

```
observeEvent(input$inTabset, {
    if (input$inTabset == "Zug") {
      num_people <- input$people3
    } else if (input$inTabset == "Bar") {
      num_people <- input$people2
    } else if (input$inTabset == "Großraumbuero") {
      num_people <- input$people
    }
      
}
)
paste(num_people)
```

However, this does not provide the sought after value from the UI. I tried several ways that did neither passed the value from my people[2|3] input to the num_people variable on user input or tab selection.

Huge thanks in advance, hope there is way to achieve this.

Comment: You are using the same ID for 3 sliderInputs - for example `sliderInput("raum",..)`.  Try defining unique IDs.

Comment: @YBS's comment and solution are likely to work.  As an additional comment, this is a case crying out for the use of a [module](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/modules.html).

Comment: Thanks for the input guys, I´ll have a look at modules for my case. Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your variable `num_people` is only available inside the observer.  If you want it outside, you can create a `reactiveVal` object.  Try this

```
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  numpeople <- reactiveVal(0)
  observeEvent(input$inTabset, {
    if (input$inTabset == "Zug") {
      num_people <- input$people3
    } else if (input$inTabset == "Bar") {
      num_people <- input$people2
    } else if (input$inTabset == "Großraumbuero") {
      num_people <- input$people
    }
    numpeople(num_people)
    print(num_people)
  })
  observe(print(numpeople()))
}
```